# Create AD Account linked to domain

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program for create AD accounts but when i'm creating an user, it is not join into AD domain and it's block me for associate an email adress to this new account.

My ad user error screenshoot : http://nsa37.casimages.com/img/2015/10/23/151023115708482493.jpg

Can anyone knows how or can help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks to help me,
Best regards,

```
Private Sub CreateADUserAccount(ByVal ldapPath As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal username2 As String, ByVal userPassword As String, ByVal admusername As String, ByVal admpw As String, ByVal addomainee As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim entry As New DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, admusername, admpw, AuthenticationTypes.Secure)
        'Création de l'Unité d'Organisation
        Dim entry1 As DirectoryEntry = entry.Children.Add(("OU=Private Administrators"), "organizationalUnit")
        Dim Verifu1 As Boolean = True
            entry1.CommitChanges()
        'Raccourci de connexion à l'Unité d'Organisation
        Dim OUentry As DirectoryEntry = entry.Children.Find("OU=Private Administrators")
        'Create first user
            Dim entry2 As DirectoryEntry = OUentry.Children.Add(("CN=" & username), "user")
            entry2.Properties.Item("samAccountName").Value = (username)
            entry2.Properties.Item("displayName").Value = username
            entry2.Properties.Item("userPrincipalName").Value = username
            entry2.CommitChanges()
        Dim entrySearch As DirectorySearcher = New DirectorySearcher(entry)
        entrySearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(SAMAccountName=" & username & "))"
        Dim OneSearchResult As SearchResult = entrySearch.FindOne
        Dim AlterUser As DirectoryEntry = OneSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry()
        AlterUser.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure
        AlterUser.Invoke("SetPassword", userPassword)
        AlterUser.CommitChanges()
        'Active Account & Password never expire
        AlterUser.Properties.Item("userAccountControl").Value = (66048)
        AlterUser.CommitChanges()
        'User doesnt need to change password after first login
        AlterUser.Properties("PwdLastSet").Value = 0
        AlterUser.CommitChanges()
        AlterUser.Close()
     End Sub
```

Comment: This link may help you out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#36

Answer (score 0):

Finnaly I resolv my problem by edit this line :

```
entry2.Properties.Item("UserPrincipalName").Value = username
```

To

```
Dim fulldomain As String = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties.DomainName.ToString
            entry2.Properties.Item("UserPrincipalName").Value = username & "@" & fulldomain
```